# How to access correctly classes from directories/subdirectories?

Tags: php

When I try to access **includes/config.php** from inside **account/index.php** I get these errors:

**Warning:** include(classes/user.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in **/var/www/htdocs/dashboard/includes/config.php** on line **6**

**Warning:** include(): Failed opening 'classes/user.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in **/var/www/htdocs/dashboard/includes/config.php** on line **6**

I define the path correctly, but when index.php access to config.php, I think config.php occurs directory problem when calling classes in config.php, I couldn't find how to solve it.

Thanks in advance.

**Here is folder structure**

```
App/
├─ account/
│  ├─ index.php
├─ classes
├─ includes/
│  ├─ config.php
├─ index.php
```

**index.php** in **account/index.php**

```
<?php
require('../includes/config.php');
?>
```

**config.php** in **includes/config.php**

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();

//include the user class, pass in the database connection
include('classes/user.php');
include('classes/phpmailer/mail.php');
include('classes/slug.php');
$user = new User($db);
?>
```

Comment: I guess that you need to traverse up one directory for your includes, i.e `include('../classes/user.php);` etc

Comment: But this time index.php in main root throws same errors. So how to connect all together? @Gowire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Sohrab said you need to give it the absolute path. You can solve this problem with `__DIR__`. (the directory of the file) to learn more about [**DIR**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.magic.php)

You should use it like:

```
require(__DIR__.'/../includes/config.php');
```

also in config.php and other files:

```
include(__DIR__.'/../classes/user.php');
include(__DIR__.'/../classes/phpmailer/mail.php');
include(__DIR__.'/../classes/slug.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

Config file looks for the files in its directory.
You should change your code to:

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();

//include the user class, pass in the database connection
include('../classes/user.php');
include('../classes/phpmailer/mail.php');
include('../classes/slug.php');
$user = new User($db);
?>
```

Comment: I tried this but index.php in main root throws same error as account/index.php

Comment: If you want to access some another directory from main you may give it absolute path (that starts with '/'). I suggest you to learn about absolute and relative path.

Comment: Okay, thank you i will learn about absolute path.